# KineticJS - Scaling stage to viewport

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm working towards a default resolution of 1366x756.

I would to scale this up and down depending on the viewport.
Similar to the example shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2012/04/06/modernizing-your-html5-canvas-games-with-offline-apis-file-apis-css3-amp-hardware-scaling.aspx

I'm kind of confused how I would get this to work in KineticJS as it abstracts away the canvas elements used.

---

What I would like to achieve is basically:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", OnResizeCalled, false);

function OnResizeCalled() {
    canvas.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}
```

I know that this isn't the perfect solution as this would stretch the canvas and not keep aspect ratio.

---

I'm currently using the following:

```
stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
stage.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
stage.setScale(window.innerWidth / 1366)
```

It's more or less what I'm looking for, but:

- mouse/touch actions aren't scaled to the new proportions.
- not the native scaling which uses the GPU to upscale the canvas object.

---

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a separate problem I was trying to help solve, the user him/herself (user848039) figured out a solution that dealt with mouse position and KineticJS scaling.

This was the question: [kineticjs stage.getAbsoluteMousePosition()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330609/kineticjs-stage-getabsolutemouseposition).

Credits go to him, but here was his formula that I modified to meet a more common KineticJS setup:

```
var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();

mousePos.x = mousePos.x/stage.getScale().x-stage.getAbsolutePosition().x/stage.getScale().x+stage.getOffset().x;
mousePos.y = mousePos.y/stage.getScale().y-stage.getAbsolutePosition().y/stage.getScale().y+stage.getOffset().y;
```

Perhaps [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/r3Cea/) isn't the best example for this, since you want the stage to be innerWidth and innerHeight. Those measurements seem to play a bit weird in  the jsFiddle frame, but if you look at the code, you'll see that I set the stage exactly the same as you mentioned above. With the new calculations for `mousePos` the `mousePos.x` and `mousePos.y` are returning the proper coordinates for your scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very interesting! I'll try this out and hopefully tick the answer. :)

Comment: Haven't tried yet, sorting out the thousands of lines of code I have. I'll tick your answer. I'll probably leave a comment later regarding my progress. Thanks :)